# Google Maps: input Lat and Long and receive images, information, name etc

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm making an app in **android studio** where the user can enter in a lat and long point and a new activity will open up with the name of the location, images and possibly some paragraphs of information.

I'm not too sure how to approach this, and which apis to use; if anyone could point me to the right direction with some handy tips and/or code snippets it would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) and the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/).

According to [the documentation for the Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), you can retrieve a place details with a query like

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters`

and you will receive a JSON or XML response with the place details.

You can even access a places photos ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)) to access the photos stored in the Places and Google+ databases.

Take into account that you will nedd an API key to query these services so you may want to check [the pricing and plans options](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/).

Comment: Thank you for this ! What's the difference between the Places and Web Services APIs?

Comment: Places is an Android API that exposes it's functionality via Java classes and Places web services is an API that exposes it's functionality via http requests